# Date input in PHP is not saving the DATE selected in SQL Server 2008 R2 using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server, date

Greeting folks!

Why does the date I selected is not saving in my SQL Server 2008 R2? However, the date saved in my DB is 1970-01-01.

Can somebody tell me why or what's the problem? or is it on my database?

This is my DATE input and I'm using CodeIgniter.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="dtconfinementfrom" value="<?php echo set_value('dtconfinementfrom'); ?>" required />
```

This is my sql data type.

```
dtconfinementfrom DATE NOT NULL
```

Comment: Might be the difference in date format.

Comment: How can I fix this problem?